# Akka 2.4.6 - where is ask (or ?) method?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I am currently learning Play with Akka and Scala.

The Akka documentation says that you can get a message back from an actor by using `?` or the `ask` method. There is however no `?` or `ask` in ActorRef class in the version of Akka I am using (2.4.6).

Was it moved somewhere or deprecated?

Comment: It's based on implicits, so you need to import it to use it (same as the pipeTo pattern): `import akka.pattern.ask`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Was it moved somewhere or deprecated?

No. `?` is defined as an [implicit def](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/pattern/AskSupport.scala#L280) inside the `AskSupport` trait and is an implicit conversion for an `ActorRef` type:

```
object AskPattern {
  implicit class Askable[T](val ref: ActorRef[T]) extends AnyVal {
    def ?[U](f: ActorRef[U] ⇒ T)(implicit timeout: Timeout): Future[U] = ask(ref, timeout, f)
}
```

As you can see, the implicit works for any `ActorRef`, as the implicit class accepts one argument of the said type. This means that the `?` method is applicable for any `ActorRef` via an [implicit conversion](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-conversions).

As @Sergey notes in the comments, in order to bring the implicit in scope, you'll need to `import akka.pattern.ask`

Comment: It's probably worth adding that in order to enable that implicit conversion, one should `import akka.pattern.ask` :)

Comment: The link to Ask.scala is broken. Is [this](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/pattern/AskSupport.scala#L280) where you you want to link to?

Comment: @Matthias Code has changed since I've answered. I'll make sure to update it.